# Distributing objects question

Tags: combinatorics

Consider 7 different objects and 4 persons. How many distributions of the objects are there if we require that 3 persons receive 2 objects and 1 person receives 1 object?

I solved as follows $\frac{7!}{2!2!2!1!}$. Am I correct?

Thanks

Comment: To be picky, what you wrote is an answer, not a solution.  Are the objects distinct or not? I assume the people are to be considered distinct!  If the objects are distinct, your answer is off by a factor of $4$. Perhaps you did not take into account the fact that the person who will receive $1$ object can be chosen in $\binom{4}{1}$ ways.

Comment: yes they are different. thank you.

Comment: If you can produce an argument that the answer (after calculation) is $2520$, your argument is likely to be correct.

Comment: @Andre, can you please show me the calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The person who will receive only one gift can be chosen in $\binom{4}{1}$ ways. For each such choice, the actual gift she will receive can be chosen in $\binom{7}{1}$ ways.  So there are 
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{7}{1}$$
ways to select the person who will receive $1$ gift only, *and* the gift she will receive.

Once we have done this, we have $6$ gifts left, and we need to give $2$ of these to each of $3$ people.

Call the $3$ lucky people A, B, and C.  The gifts for A can be chosen in $\binom{6}{2}$ ways.  For *each* such way, there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways select the gifts for B. And once we have done that, what C gets is determined. If you like, there are then $\binom{2}{2}$ ways to decide what C gets.  It follows that the total number of ways of doing the job is
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{7}{1}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}.$$
Finally, calculate. We get $2520$.

**Comment:** You may have been using *multinomial coefficients*, or some related formula.  First choose who will get only one gift. This can be done in $\binom{4}{1}$ ways.  Suppose that for example the people are called A, B, C, D, and D is to get only one gift. So we want to distribute $7$ objects in the pattern $2$-$2$-$2$-$1$. By a remembered formula, the number of ways to do this is 
$$\binom{7}{2,2,2,1}\qquad\text{that is,}\qquad \frac{7!}{2!2!2!1!}.$$
So our total count is
$$\binom{4}{1}\frac{7!}{2!2!2!1!}.$$
From the answer you arrived at, I assume that your reasoning was along the lines of this comment, and only the factor $\binom{4}{1}$ was missing.

Comment: thank you very much for your tome and help. I now understand fully. I will try to practice more with this reasoning.